# Googleservices.json says not present when it is

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-play-services

[image]
Im learning flutter and trying to install firebase and it keeps saying that "google-services.json" can not be found, even though I have it in the right place, also tried many other places what it actuall says is "Exit code 1 from: C:\Users\Samwise\Desktop\chatapp3\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)"

Thank you so much.

also my gradles ---

```
 build app gradle-------------------------

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
compileSdkVersion 26

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.test"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


implementation'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
implementation'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
implementation'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.0'
implementation'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
implementation'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'

//firebase
implementation'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1'
implementation'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.2.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

build root gradle

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: gradle file doesnt seems to have google-service plugin can you please show app level gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Firebase version that uses google service 3.2.0 is not yet supported based on the comment in the [repo issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16266):

> Firebase has moved on to version 12+ and uses version 3.2.0 of the
>   google-services Gradle plugin. The flutter/plugins repo should follow
>   suit.

I have 3.1.2 happily working, so you could try that.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
```